# WP_Query by post ID doesn't work if post is in custom post_status

Tags: wp-query, post-status

I want to display a single post by its ID using [WP_Query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). To do this, I use the following argument:

```
$args = array(
   'p' => 61202);
```

That should work, but does not seem to work **if** the post is in a custom `post_status`.

To fix this, I tried the following:

```
$args = array(
   'p' => 61202, // id of post
   'post_type' => 'any', // apply to all post types
   'post_status' => 'my_custom_status' // the custom post status
);
```

But this still does not work. **Why?!**

Is there a known bug? I am running this code in the wp-admin area. It works fine if the post is in any of the WP core post statuses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WP_Query` has [a bug (#29167)](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29167) when you try to fetch posts with (almost?) any other status than `publish`. This bug seems to be fixed in trunk. I haven’t tested it, so I cannot tell if it covers your use case. Try it, and give feedback there if it doesn’t.

There are two workarounds:

1. Use `get_post( $post_id )`. This runs its own query and isn’t affected by this bug.
2. Use a custom DB query if you don’t know the post IDs:

```php
    $sql      = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = %s AND post_type = %s";
    $prepared = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $status, $post_type );
    $posts    = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
```

Comment: I can confirm that the patch posted in the bug report does indeed work.