# WP_Query will not display draft posts

Tags: wp-query, post-status

I'm trying to get `WP_Query` to display ALL posts in an array but only ones with status published are showing:

```
global $wp_query;

$ids = array(130, 132);
$args = array(
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'auto-draft', 'future', 'private', 'inherit'), 
     // 'post_status' => 'any', // same output
    'post__in' => $ids, 
    'post_type' => 'alpha'  
);

$q = new WP_Query($args);

foreach ($q->posts as $post) {
    echo $post->id;
}
```

However this displays post id's regardless of their status:

```
// post status
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    echo get_post_status($id);
}
```

This is fresh install of the Bones theme with no plugins. How do I display all posts in the array regardless of status? I must be missing something in the codex...

Comment: Try using `'post_status' => 'any'`

Comment: Probably the same problem as here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176949/wp-query-by-post-id-doesnt-work-if-post-is-in-custom-post-status

Comment: Try: $args = array('post_status' => 'any', 'post__in' => $ids, 'post_type' => 'alpha', 'posts_per_page' => -1);

Comment: Did the link from @toscho not work. It would be nice if you leave some feedback if you need extra help. :-)

Comment: Thank you @PieterGoosen for that nice comment, I have not gotten to testing those solutions because of day work. However I am not utilizing a custom status... I'll be sure to report

Answer (score 1):

You can just `'post_status' => 'any'`.

Here is the completed code.

```
    global $wp_query;

    $ids   = array(130,132);
    $args  = array(
        'post_status' => 'any', 
        // 'post_status' => 'any', // same output
        'post__in' => $ids, 
        'post_type' => 'alpha'  
    );

    $q     = new WP_Query($args);

    foreach ($q->posts as $post) {
        echo $post->id;

    }
```

Official docs on `post_status` option
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#status-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:

```
<?php

global $wp_query;

$ids   = array(130,132);
$args  = array(
            'post_status' => array(        
            'publish',                      
            'pending',                      
            'draft',                        
            'auto-draft',                   
            'future',                       
            'private',                     
            'inherit',                     
            ),
            'post__in' => $ids, 
            'post_type' => 'alpha'
        );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ){
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        echo get_the_ID();
    endwhile;
}

wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```